# Multiple clickTags for html5 file in Google AdManager

Tags: html, google-ad-manager, clicktag

I have an html5 file that has multiple links that need to have click tags for tracking.

I can't seem to find a way to get both clickTags to show up in Google Ad Manager. Just the first one.

```
<body>
<script>
    var clickTag = "https://www.example-1.com";
    var clickTagOther = "https://www.example-2.com";
</script>

<img src="example-image.png" alt="Web Logos" usemap="#logos" />

<map name="logos">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,65,130,130" href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,485,300,585" href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTagOther)" />
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue.

I needed to name the second clickTag `clickTag2` rather than `clickTagOther`.